# React Native: How to make ScrollView scroll for just one item in it?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have an image rendered inside a scrollview component and the dimensions of the image are fixed as (height: 200, and width from device dimension).
Also the style of the scrollview is set as (flex: 1 not contentContainerStyle).

But the image doesn't scroll properly and snaps back when I scroll.

I understand that this is because there is only one item in the scrollView.

How to force scroll the content inside the scrollView even if there is only one item in it?

Comment: Do you want to zoom inside the image? Can you add screenshot of what exactly you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ScrollView within a an enclosing